# Porqué una lista y un NumPy array se comportan diferente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dibujo una función a partir de un array:
[image: Gráfica a partir del array]

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def f(x):
    return x**2 + 2
x = np.array(range(-100, 101))
# Set up the graph
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid()

# Plot x against f(x)
plt.plot(x,f(x), color='purple') 

plt.show()
```

Cuando lo quiero hacer a partir de una lista sustituyendo

```
x = np.array(range(-100, 101))
```

por

```
x = list(range(-100, 101))
```

obtengo el siguiente error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'"

Sin embargo, cuando hago

```
x = np.array(range(-100, 101)) 
print (x)
```

obtengo el mismo resultado que cuando hago:

```
x = list(range(-100, 101))
print (x)
```

El resultado es en ambos casos una lista de enteros desde -100 a 100 de uno en uno, encerrados por un paréntesis recto.
A qué se debe el error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se comportan diferente porque son *tipos* diferentes. En Python cada tipo define su propio comportamiento.

Cuando haces `a * b` lo que ocurre depende de los tipos de los datos a que se refieren `a` y `b`. Si el dato referenciado por `a` implementa un método llamado `__mul__()`, se ejecutará `a.__mul__(b)`, por tanto el tipo al que pertenece `a` puede definir qué significa para él la multiplicación.

De este modo  `2*3` tiene un significado muy distinto a `"2"*3`, o a `[2]*3`

Del mismo modo `numpy` define un nuevo tipo `array` para el cual redefine todos los operadores, para que se comporten *vectorialmente*.

Así puedes hacer `a + 2` y si `a` es un array numpy el resultado es que *todos* sus elementos resultan incrementados en dos unidades. No es esto lo que sucedería si `a` fuese una lista estándar, pues en ese caso no está definido el operador `+` entre lista y entero (si lo está en cambio entre dos listas, con el resultado de concatenar).

En tu caso ocurre algo análogo pero con el operador `**`, que numpy implementa en un método de la clase `array` llamado `__pow__()`, que opera también *vectorialmente* (esto es, para todos los elementos del array). Así `a**2` eleva al cuadrado a todos los elementos del array numpy `a`. Pero si `a` es una lista, ese operador no está definido.